# Should this tent's seams be sealed outside or inside?

Tags: tents, waterproofing

Should this tent's wall/floor seam (shown below) be sealed inside or outside?  The instructions on the bottle of Coghlan's sealer says " ... apply a thin even film to the stitching on the coated side of the fabric (or inside of item)", which seems to imply "inside" to me.  But, the visible stitching is all on the outside.  (And, the water will collect a little between the orange trim and the tent wall, so shouldn't that be sealed)?

[image: outside of tent]
[image]

Comment: That is where I would seal it. You could seal both inside and outside if you have a lot of sealant.

Comment: And by "that", you mean "outside", right?

Comment: Yes, I would seal the sewed seam first, and if I had more sealant, after the first dried I'd invert the tent and apply on the inside. With waterproofed fabric, the holes from the sewing are a prime water entry point.

Comment: I would guess you actually want to go with inside. The little bit of water collecting in orange doesn't really matter. Sealing the inside will keep the actual joint sealed better so the inside (which you care about stays dry).

Comment: Alternatively do 6 inches on the inside and do 6 inches on the outside of other end. Pour some water on both and see which you like better. Doing both sides everywhere seems like overkill.

Comment: Hmm.  I did both outside and inside.   Less water is getting into the tent, but it still leaks.  The main problem is where the different sections come together (the point of the triangle in both pictures).